# why does GCC "expect an expression"?

Tags: c, expression

```
#define rows 2
#define cols 2
#define NUM_CORNERS 4

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int the_corners[NUM_CORNERS];
    int array[rows][cols] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    corners(array, the_corners);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%d\n", the_corners[i]);
}

int corners (int array[rows][cols], int the_corners[]) {
    the_corners = {
        array[0][cols-1],
        array[0][0],
        array[rows-1][0],
        array[rows-1][cols-1]
    };
}
```

I get these weird errors and i have no idea why:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘corners’
prog.c: In function ‘corners’:
prog.c:15: error: expected expression before
```

Comment: Please paste your code in here, rather than use an external link

Comment: I'd suggest you to use UPPERCASE for all your `#define` constants. People usually do not expect lowercase things - especially if they aren't functions - to be preprocessor macros/constants.

Comment: gotcha - ...how would that help the C though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `the_corners = { ... }` syntax is an array initialization, not an assignment. I don't have a copy of the standard handy so I can't quote chapter and verse but you want to say this:

```
void corners (int array[rows][cols], int the_corners[]) {
    the_corners[0] = array[0][cols-1];
    the_corners[1] = array[0][0];
    the_corners[2] = array[rows-1][0];
    the_corners[3] = array[rows-1][cols-1];
}
```

I also took the liberty of changing `int corners` to `void corners` as you weren't returning anything. And your `main` also needs a return value and you forgot to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: i lopped off the include, since i'm including a library of my own that includes stdio.h

Comment: @tekknolagi: Fair enough, I just figured that you didn't have all your compiler's warning flags enabled (or were ignoring warnings which is just as bad) and might have missed the missing include.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use an initialiser expression as an assignment. This isn't valid, even in C99, because the type of the_corners is `int*`, not `int[4]`. In this case you would be best off assigning each element individually.

Answer (score 0):

The main doesn' know about your function. Either move the function decleration above the main or prototype it before the main:

```
int corners (int array[rows][cols], int the_corners[NUM_CORNERS]);
```

Comment: okay, that did not do much.... it still expects an expression before the `{` token

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NROWS 2
#define NCOLUMNS 2
#define NCORNERS 4

int corners(int (*arr)[NCOLUMNS], int* the_corners);

int main() {
    int i;
    int the_corners[NCORNERS];
    int arr[NCOLUMNS][NROWS] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    corners(arr, the_corners);

    for (i = 0; i < NCORNERS; i++)
        printf("%d\n", the_corners[i]);

    return 0;
}

int corners(int (*arr)[NCOLUMNS], int* the_corners) {

        the_corners[0] = arr[0][NCOLUMNS-1];
        the_corners[1] = arr[0][0];
        the_corners[2] = arr[NROWS-1][0];
        the_corners[3] = arr[NROWS-1][NCOLUMNS-1];

        return 0;
}
```

You can read [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) about passing a 2D array to a function.